# Hiding activity and attachments for a profile

Tags: profile, account, attachment, contact, activities

I want to hide notes and attachments, Activity of Account and Contact object for a specific profile.

Ie., that profile can view all the accounts and contacts but they cant able to see the attachments and Activity of the record.

I have removed it from the page layout but while user search something, The result produces the related activity and attachment.